# Is there an easy way to load an external header on all pages using HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a site with 20+ pages and updating the main links on all pages becomes quite tiresome. I have been able to do this using PHP on a Wordpress template I created a while back, but the current site I am working on uses only HTML, CSS and jQuery and I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: no. html has no "programability". you need something server-side for this kind of thing. if you don't/can't have php, then consider going old school, and using something like server-side includes.

Comment: I tried using the iframe element and it almost worked, but it left out all the CSS. Is iframe the best method for this?

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, I'll look into that.

Comment: you can use whatever you want. there is no "best" option. they all have positives and negatives.

Comment: `<iframe>` is rarely the best method for anything. Use it only if you must. Something like a static site generator (Jekyll, etc.) that processes includes/templates/etc. and leaves you with finished HTML (no PHP) is a better bet.

Answer (score 3):

[HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) imports should do the trick

```
<link rel="import" href="/path/to/imports/stuff.html">
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't realize this was now supported.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could send off an ajax request using jQuery's [get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method but it's not really ideal. Other than that, you could use an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

One way to write your header as a JavaScript file like this:

```
// header.js
document.write('\
    <em>Add your HTML code here</em>\
');
```

And then load your js file into your html files:

```
<html>   
   <body>
      <p>This html content is written before header</p>
      <script src="header.js"></script>
      <p>And this one after</p>
   </body>
</html>
```